# What is the most "angular way" to set up angularjs and different google maps services and functions?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, model-view-controller, google-maps-api-3, angularjs

I'm developing an an app which uses the Google distance matrix, the directions service and some map-features like custom markers. Where would you put all this different functionality? Inside of a controller, a service, a directive or even a module with combination of them? What would be the most angular way to do so in your opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All manipulations with DOM in Angular should be done through directives. It's the "angular way". There is an [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.com/) project that have Google map example.

Look at theirs google map directive [code](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/blob/master/modules/directives/map/map.js).

Comment: I was not aware that they're using a directive. Interesting. I will play around with that approach a little tomorrow. But still the driving matrix is more of a service. Would you recommend to split up Google Maps functionality? Logically this makes sense, but I'm not sure yet how nice it will work in practice due to the shared dependencies. Even more problematic will be the directives service, as there is quite a lot stuff thrown together...

Comment: Yep, I would recommend this approach. You could place logic in a service and then inject It into directive.